# Logging to multiple text files from dynamically loaded context

Tags: c#, serilog

What I'm looking for is as follows:

- Base Logging instance for the main application, logs to text file Main.txt. This has all base settings for destructuring etc and must continue to log from main application till it closes.
- The main application dynamically opens other assemblies using reflection, I want a new log file for each unique assembly executed with an ILogger instance passed to the assembly as a parameter. This log instance should close once the loaded assembly returns.

From what I've looked at a ForContext with Filter in the Logger configuration can identify and filter out the 'context' from each of the executed assemblies.

My questions are:

- How can I append WriteTo.Logger during runtime? I don't want to lose the main configuration static reference for the main application.
- How do I Filter in the new Logger based on the context given in Log.ForContext?

Is it simply a case of setting a new LoggerConfiguration? Will that affect the current 'main' log?

Answer (score 0):

For know where you are, you can use :

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
```

If you do a static public var for Log, you can access to it everywhere.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but the question is not about how to identify the current application class or method. The question is how to configure mutiple dynamic loggers during runtime, please see the original questions.